# using UnitOfWork and Repository Pattern with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

I'm gonna to use repository and UnitOfwork in my data access layer to do this take a look at one contact aggregateroot

```
 public interface IAggregateRoot
    {
    }
```

this is my Generic repository interface :

```
 public interface IRepository<T>
        {
            IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
            T FindBy(params Object[] keyValues);
            void Add(T entity);
            void Update(T entity);
            void Delete(T entity);

        }
```

and my POCO Contact class in Model

```
 public class Contact :IAggregateRoot
        {
            public Guid Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Email { get; set; }
            public string Title { get; set; }
            public string Body { get; set; }
            public DateTime CreationTime { get; set; }
        }
```

and this my IContactRepository  that inherit from IRepository and also maybe has it is own method

```
 public interface IContactRepository : IRepository<Contact>
        {
        }
```

Now I have done in IUitOfWork and UnitOfwork like this

```
public interface IUnitOfWork 
    {
        IRepository<Contact> ContactRepository { get; }
    }

public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
    {
        private readonly StatosContext _statosContext = new StatosContext();
        private IRepository<Contact> _contactUsRepository;

 public IRepository<Contact> ContactRepository
        {
            get { return _contactUsRepository ?? (_contactUsRepository = new Repository<Contact>(_statosContext)); }
        }
}
```

also about my Repository

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class, IAggregateRoot
    {
       //implementing methods 
    }
```

I can do all CRUD operation with accessing Repositories with UnitOfwork in Service , example :

```
_unitOfWork.ContactRepository.Add(contact);
            _unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
```

but I want to do like this

_

```
ContactRepository.Add(contact);
            _unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
```

(get CRUD and generic method via _ContactRepository No by _unitOfWork.ContactRepository)
Because I want to get ContactRepository method to some specific queries ,
anybody help please ??

Comment: Maybe that's a little bit beside the point, but I moved away from fully fledged repositories in favor of simpler solution: introducing a slim `IDbContext` interface and using the `DbContext` through said interface. Since `DbContext` is UoW and repository in one out of the box, it's quite simple and effective...

Comment: sorry I didn't Got it ! could you please give an example , I only found http://www.primaryobjects.com/CMS/Article122.aspx useful but it is different

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not a *direct* answer to your question, but it might simplify things a little bit and reduce duplication.

When you use e.g. EntityFramework Power Tools to reverse-engineer Code First (or just use Code First in general), you end up with the `DbContext` class that serves as a UoW and repository in one, e.g.:

```
public partial class YourDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Contact> Contacts {get; set;}
}
```

Now, if you want things to be testable, there's an easy way: introduce a  very thin interface:

```
public interface IDbContext
{
    IDbSet<T> EntitySet<T>() where T : class;
    int SaveChanges();
    //you can reveal more methods from the original DbContext, like `GetValidationErrors` method or whatever you really need.
}
```

then make another file with second part of the partial class:

```
public partial class YourDbContext : IDbContext
{
     public IDbSet<T> EntitySet<T>() where T : class
     {
         return Set<T>();
     }
}
```

Ta-da! Now you can inject `IDbContext` with `YourDbContext` backing it up:

```
//context is an injected IDbContext:
var contact = context.EntitySet<Contact>().Single(x => x.Id == 2);    
contact.Name = "Updated name";
context.EntitySet<Contact>().Add(new Contact { Name = "Brand new" });
context.SaveChanges();
```

Now if you want to have control over the disposal of the context, then you'd have to write your own (*gasp*) `IDbContextFactory` (generic or not, depending what you need) and inject that factory instead.

No need to write your own `Find`, `Add` or `Update` methods now, `DbContext` will handle that appropriately, it's easier to introduce explicit transactions and everything is nicely hidden behind interfaces (`IDbContext`, `IDbSet`).

By the way, the `IDbContextFactory` would be an equivalent to NHibernate's `ISessionFactory` and `IDbContext` - `ISession`. I wish EF had this out of the box, too.

Comment: Be aware, when unit testing this with a mock or fake, you may get different results with a real DbContext EntityFramework expressions work differently than LinqToObjects expressions (due to the translation to SQL).  For instance, LinqToObjects will throw exceptions if create expressions with nullable columns that are in fact null, while LinqToEntities won't.  Also, L2O will allow method invocations within the expression, but L2E won't (except for limited special functions).

Comment: @MystereMan True, if you're stubbing or switching the repository to a fake, that should be taken into consideration. If you're just mocking it (and leaving the data testing to integration tests), it's the easiest solution there is. :)

Comment: This helped me simplify my abstraction with/over DbContext (essentially a UofW). It was always bugging me that I couldn't quite get the DbContext and my abstraction to fit together nicely...this was what I was looking for. I do have a repository layer rather than use DbSet directly for them though.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the Doctor, DbContext is already a UnitOfWork, and adding another UoW abstraction on top of it is typically redundant, unless you think it's highly likely you might switch database technologies in the future.

I don't agree, however, with treating DbSet's as repositories, since this tightly couples your queries to the methods that use them.  If you need to change a query, you have to do it everywhere you use it.

I prefer to either use a stand-alone repository (or service interface, they serve similar functions) or to use more of a CQRS system for Command/Query Seperation, an use query objects.

Comment: thanks for your answer ,you mean I can remove all about UoW as Entity framework supports it ?? But as my reference is Pro asp.net design pattern by scott millett and he has cover entity framework via UOW pattern ! maybe in earlier version of Entity Framework it was Not supported yeah ???

Comment: @EricNielsen - Well, it's always had some level of UnitOfWork, but DbContext, which was added in 4.1 of EF is much simpler and straight forward.  In any event, lots of people still recommend using UoW, I simply don't see the need for further abstraction in most apps.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the UnitOfWork class you need to implement DBContext or ObjectContext.

UnitOfWork segregates all transactions regardless of the system. EF is only for DB connection. Even if your system is only using DB still it is better to keep a separate UnitOfWork class for future expansions.

And inside the unit of work Commit(), you can call the internally implemented DBContext.SaveChanges().

This DBcontext will be accessible to all repositories declared inside unitofwork. So repositories add or delete from DBcontext and unitOfwork commits it.

When you have scenarios spanning different storages eg: Cloud Blobs, table storage etc. You could implement them inside UnitofWork just like you implemented a EF context. And some repositories can access Table Storage and some EF context.

Tip: Implementing ObjectContext instead of DBContext gives you an edge in caching scenarios. And you have more options in extending your framework.