# How to mock an interface for entity framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing

I followed the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16467576/using-unitofwork-and-repository-pattern-with-entity-framework) to create a interface for the DbContext in entity framework.  The problem is, I have no idea how to use it to unit test.  My controller that I am trying to test has two constructors.  One has no parameters and sets an IDbContext instance variable to a new DbContext. The other takes an IDbContext and sets the same instance variable. The method I am testing simply does this

```
return context.EntitySet<question>().ToList();
```

Below is my failing attempt to use Moq and test the controller.  I haven't changed anything in the interface or partial class listed in the answer.  Perhaps I need to add something?

```
            Mock<IDbContext> mockContext = new Mock<IDbContext>();
        question TestQuestion = new question { 
            Id = 1,
            ToAsk = "Did this test work?"
        };
        mockContext.Object.EntitySet<question>().Add(TestQuestion);

        QuestionsController controller = new QuestionsController( mockContext.Object );
        List<DHT.Entity.Models.question> questions = controller.Get();
        Assert.AreEqual(questions.Count, 1);
```

I am pretty new to .NET and C#, so if I am doing everything completely wrong, let me know.  The approach in the link I gave seemed simpler then implementing an entire repository pattern.  I am just trying to be able to find the easiest way to unit test my code.

Comment: Effort is a nice unit testing tool for EF.

Comment: Thanks Shawn, I will have to take a look at that.  It looks promising.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use FakeDbSet NuGet Package or implement your own `InMemoryDbSet<T>` class (`InMemoryDbSet<T>` that is used in code snippet is the one from FakeDbSet package):

```
Mock<IDbContext> mockContext = new Mock<IDbContext>();
question TestQuestion = new question { 
    Id = 1,
    ToAsk = "Did this test work?"
};
IDbSet<question> questions = new InMemoryDbSet<question>(true){ TestQuestion };
mockContext.Setup(c => c.EntitySet<question>()).Returns(questions);

QuestionsController controller = new QuestionsController( mockContext.Object );
List<DHT.Entity.Models.question> questions = controller.Get();
Assert.AreEqual(questions.Count, 1);
```

Comment: Thanks!  I was able to get this to work.  For some reason the true param on InMemoryDbSet causes a null object reference though.